# Group by day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `conversations` with an `inserted_at` column

I want to draw a chart showing the amount of `conversations` created over time.

I'd like to be able to group the data by either the date, the day of week, and the time of date, to show possible trends.

I'll be using intervals of 7 days, 1 month and 6 months.

Example:

Interval: `1 month` group by `day of week`

I'd like something like

```
| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|
| 11     | 22      | 19        | 17       | 10     |
```

or interval: `7 days` group by `date`

```
| 1/1 | 2/1 | 3/1 | 4/1 | 5/1 | 6/1 | 7/1 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 11  | 22  | 19  | 17  | 10  | 10  | 7   |
```

What is the best way to accomplish this (examples would be greatly appreciated), and is PostgreSQL fit for these kind of queries?

Lastly, are there any special sort of indexes that will improve such queries?

Comment: Seems like some kind of `pivot` problem.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is not a pivot question. It is just aggregation.

Answer (score 14):

Days of the week:

```
select
    count(extract(dow from inserted_at) = 1 or null) as monday,
    count(extract(dow from inserted_at) = 2 or null) as tuesday,
    count(extract(dow from inserted_at) = 3 or null) as wednesday,
    count(extract(dow from inserted_at) = 4 or null) as thursday,
    count(extract(dow from inserted_at) = 5 or null) as friday,
from conversations
```

`count` only counts `not null` values. `false or null` is `null` so only `true` will be counted.

In newer versions there is an aggregation `filter`:

```
count(*) filter (where extract(dow from inserted_at) = 4) as thursday
```

Comment: Why the `or null` condition?

Comment: Wow, that's tricky three-valued-logic :) I'll probably keep my `count(case when extract(dow from inserted_at) = 1 then 1 end)`

Answer (score 4):

A simple `group by` would do the trick:

```
select 
  extract(dow from inserted_at)
  , count(*)
from conversations
where inserted_at between date '2016-08-08' and '2016-08-08' + interval '7 days'
group by 1;
```

And an improved version of that query (to make sure that days with count 0 are included as well):

```
with week as
(
   SELECT s.d day FROM generate_series(1,7) s(d)
)
select
  week.day
  , count(extract(dow from c.inserted_at))
from days 
left join conversations c on week.day = extract(dow from c.inserted_at)
     and c.inserted_at between now() and now() + interval '7 days'
group by week.day
order by week.day;
```

An index on `inserted_at` column would help to quickly select the relevant interval.

Comment: would it make sense to index on `dow` as it has only 7 possible values, ie. relatively low selectivity?

Comment: Yeah, on second thought an index on `dow` is probably not the best idea.